# Как отправить и отфильтровать данные по строке

Tags: asp.net-core, angular

Я хочу по url строке выводить информацию товара. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так предполагаю, что мне нужно отправить строку на сервер, а потом отправить обратно отфильтрованные данные по строке на клиент. Собственно, пытался это реализовать, но не получилось.
Контроллер сервера:

```
 private readonly DataContext _context;
    private List<Clothes> vendor;
    public ProductVendorController(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetClothesUrl()
    {
        return Ok( vendor.ToList());
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetVendorClothes(string data)
    {
        var find = (from dadsa in _context.Clothes.Where(p => p.VendorCode == data)
                select dadsa
            ).ToListAsync();
        vendor = await find;
        return Ok();
    }
```

Сервис:

```
  public VendorFind(Vendor: string): Observable<string> {

        return this.http.post<string>(
          `${environment.apiUrl}/${this.urlVendor}`,
          Vendor
        );
      }
      public VendorFindGet():Observable<Clothes>{
          return this.http.get<Clothes>(
            `${environment.apiUrl}/${this.urlVendor}`);
    
        }
```

Компонент:

```
 VendorCode:string = "";
  private subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private clothesService:ClothesServiceService,private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.subscription = this.activateRoute.params.subscribe(params => this.VendorCode = params['VendorCode'] );
  }
  vendorUpdated = new EventEmitter<string>();
  info:any = new Clothes;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.clothesService
      .VendorFind(this.VendorCode)
      .subscribe((vendor: string) => this.vendorUpdated.emit(vendor));
    this.clothesService
      .VendorFindGet()
      .subscribe((result:Clothes)=>(this.info = result));
      console.log("vendor",this.VendorCode);
      console.log("info",this.info);


  }
```

Модуль маршрута:

```
 { path: 'Clothes/Product/:VendorCode', component: ProductPageComponent }
```

Пример HTML компонента:

```html
<h1>{{info.name}}</h1>
<span>Артикул: {{info.vendorCode}}</span>
<h1>Цена: {{info.price}}.</h1>
```

UPD:
Фронт:

```
{ path: 'Clothes/Product/:VendorCode', component: ProductPageComponent}
```

Бэкенд:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "ProductVendor",
    pattern: "{controller =  ProductVendor}/{action}/{id?}");
```

UPD 2: Собственно, на вкладке с товарами, когда пользователь нажимает посмотреть или вводит url с артикулом, то загружается страница товара, которая берется с БД.

Вкладка с товарами:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Страница продукта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Собственно, на вкладке с товарами, когда пользователь нажимает посмотреть или вводит url с артикулом, то загружается страница товара, которая берется с БД." - если так работает - то тогда все нормально

Comment: К сожалению, это не работает. Возможно, что я что-то не так сделал или что-то ещё, но этот вопрос и так слишком затянулся в комментариях. Главное, что вы указали на мои ошибки, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с серверной части, экшена.

```
[HttpPost]
// обычно пишут так, чтобы в строке можно было передать [HttpPost({id})]
// и еще для получения данных рекомендуется использовать метод GET
public async Task<ActionResult> GetVendorClothes(string data)
{
    // здесь ен вижу смысла с асинхронности, но да ладно
    var find = (from dadsa in _context.Clothes.Where(p => p.VendorCode == data)
            select dadsa
        ).ToListAsync();
    // почему бы не использовать FirstOrDefault вместо Where... вам же нужно одну запись найти
    vendor = await find;
    // ну и последняя проблемаю...Вы данные отобрали, но не возвратили их
    return Ok();
}
```

Переписываем и получаем

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetVendorClothes(string id)
{
    var finder = _context.Clothes.FirstOrDefault(f => f.VendorCode == id);
    return new JsonResult(finder);
}
```

Теперь мы можем получить объект по запросу http://localgost:1111/api/{controller}/getVendorClosest/{id}

Осталось переделать сервис ангуляра под этот запрос (возможно и роуты нужно затронуть по id) а так плюс минус у вас должно заработать. Единственный совет дам - хранить данные в сервисе и в html потом забирать через пайп async... Если не знаете как сделать - напишите, я дополню ответ

Update

Перейдем к клиентской части.

Создадим модели, с которыми будем работать на бэке и на фронте

```
// интерфейс для данных с бэка
export interface BClothes {
   ClothesId: number;
   VendorCode: string;
   Name: string;
   Image: string;
   Amount: number;
   Price: number;
}

// класс для фронта. Класс для того, чтобы задавать конструктор для меньшего количества кода
export class FClothes {
   clothesId: number;
   vendorCode: string;
   name: string;
   image: string;
   amount: number;
   price: number;
}
```

Сервис (нужен для реализации бизнес логики)

```
@Injectable()
export class ClothesService {
   // тут храню полученные данные, теперь чтобы получить данные в любом компоненте, нужно всего лишь забрать этот сервис
   clothes: BehaviorSubject<Array<FClothes>> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<FClothes>>([]);
   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}
   
   // этот метод получает весь список, в аргументе обычно пихают пэйджинг или фильтра
   getClothesList(): void {
     this.httpClient
        .get<Array<BClothes>>("link")
        .pipe(
           // забочусь об отписании подписки после выполнения запроса
           take(1)
        )
        .subscribe((res: Array<BClothes>) => {
           // записываю результат
           this.clothes.next(res.map(m => ({
               clothesId: m.ClothesId;
               vendorCode: m.VendorCode;
               name: m.Name;
               image: m.Image;
               amount: m.Amount;
               price: m.Price;
           })));
         });
   }

   // теперь получается что у меня есть все данные, и они хранятся в известой мне переменной, и при желании я могу их использовать. 
   // Обычно дополнительный метод по получению инфы по id или еще чему-то делается для следующего: 
   // 1. В общей таблицы зачастую не за чем светить много информации дабы не перегружать UX 
   // 2. Ну и скорось работы тоже никто не отменял. 
   // Поэтому, когда гружу общий список, то гружу не все поля по каждому объекту, а часть. 
   // И потом, когда проваливаюсь в конкретный объект, то уже дополучаю все данные.
   getClothesById(id: string): Observable<FClothes>{
      return this.gttpClient
         .get<BClothes>(`link/${id}`)
         .pipe(
            map((m: BClothes) => ({
               clothesId: m.ClothesId;
               vendorCode: m.VendorCode;
               name: m.Name;
               image: m.Image;
               amount: m.Amount;
               price: m.Price;
            })),
            take(1)
         )
   }
}
```

Ну а дальше момент с отображением...наш компонент (сама страничка)

```
@Component({
   ...
   providers: [ClothesService]
})
export class ClothesComponent implements OnInit {
   clothes: Observable<Array<FClothes>>;
   constructor(private clothesService: ClothesService){
      this.clothes = this.clothesService.clothes;
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.clothesService.getClothesList();
   }

   showDetails(selected: FClothes): void {
      // открыть компонент (к примеру модалку)
      // и в ней сделать запрос на получение по id
   }
}
```

Ну и теперь html

```
<div class="clothes_container">
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Названи</th>
            <th>Кол-во</th>
            <th>Цена</th>
            <th></th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr *ngFor="let cl of clothes | async">
            <th>{{cl.name}}</th>
            <th>{{cl.amount}}</th>
            <th>{{cl.price}}</th>
            <th>
               <button (click)="showDetails(cl)">Подробнее</button>
            </th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
<div>
```

Comment: Дополните, если не сложно.

Comment: @witchblvd дополнил, если будут вопросы - пишите

Comment: Извините, что так часто вас спрашиваю, но как теперь быть с маршрутизацией? Дополнил маршрутизацию в вопросе.

Comment: @witchblvd а макапы есть? или планы? маршрутизацию нужно в соответсвии к макапам и UI/UX делать

Comment: Я не очень-то знаком с этим словом, но предполагаю, что вам нужно увидеть UI/UX страницу продукта. Если это так - могу дополнить в ответе.

Comment: @witchblvd Да, добавьте хоть примерно как у вас должен выглядеть интерфейс - и я вас наведу, как бы я организовал код

Comment: Дополнил в вопросе.